# Create ActiveRecord has_one through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Given the ActiveRecord models and associations below, I need to add a has_one `:owner` association on the account model to reference a user whose `account_user` role is set to "owner".

**AccountUser model** have a role attribute

```
class AccountUser < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:user, :admin, :owner]

  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Account Model** Has many users through account users.

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_users
  has_many :users, through: :account_users
  has_one  :owner, -> { where(role: :owner) } #, correct options here.
end
```

**User Model** Has many accounts through account users

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_users
  has_many :accounts, through: :account_users
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make an intermediate association `account_owner`:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_users
  has_many :users, through: :account_users

  has_one :account_owner, -> { where(role: :owner) }, class_name: 'AccountUser'
  has_one :owner, through: :account_owner, source: :user
end
```